# Clickhouse default http handlers not supported

Tags: http, nodes, clickhouse

I have been trying to run clickhouse on ec2 instance from terraform. So far the ec2 instance runs well and I have access to the http localhost:8123. However when I try to access the localhost:8123/play I get the following message:

```
There is no handle /play

Use / or /ping for health checks.
Or /replicas_status for more sophisticated health checks.

Send queries from your program with POST method or GET /?query=...

Use clickhouse-client:

For interactive data analysis:
    clickhouse-client

For batch query processing:
    clickhouse-client --query='SELECT 1' > result
    clickhouse-client < query > result
```

I don't understand why this is happening as I was not getting that error when running in local.
When I check the status of the clickhouse server I get the following output:

```
● clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Mar 25 12:14:35 systemd[1]: Started ClickHouse Server.
Mar 25 12:14:35 clickhouse-server[11774]: Include not found: clickhouse_remote_servers
Mar 25 12:14:35 clickhouse-server[11774]: Include not found: clickhouse_compression
Mar 25 12:14:35 clickhouse-server[11774]: Logging warning to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log
Mar 25 12:14:35 clickhouse-server[11774]: Logging errors to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log
Mar 25 12:14:35 clickhouse-server[11774]: Include not found: networks
Mar 25 12:14:35 clickhouse-server[11774]: Include not found: networks
Mar 25 12:14:37 clickhouse-server[11774]: Include not found: clickhouse_remote_servers
Mar 25 12:14:37 clickhouse-server[11774]: Include not found: clickhouse_compression
```

I don't know if this will help but maybe it is related to the problem.(logs file are empty)

Another question that I have and that has nothing to do with the problem above, is about the understanding of how clickhouse works because we hear many different articles talking about clickhouse but none seem very clear to me. We often hear about "nodes" in the articles that I've been reading. So far I think that clickhouse works with servers on which we put clusters. Inside those clusters we put shards and in each of those shards we put replicas, the so called "nodes". As we will be running in production I just want to make sure that when we talk about "nodes" we are talking about container which act as compute units or it is completely something else.

So far I've tried to open all port ingress and egress but it did not fix the problem. I've checked the clickhouse documentation which mention custom http endpoint but none talk about this error.

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed it by running sudo clickhouse start instead of sudo service clickhouse-server start. Not quite sure what is the difference but the http endpoint problem is solved. However I still wonder for the question about the nodes

Comment: The cause was that I was not running the latest build of ClickHouse and thus the endpoints didn't exist